# Intalling gdb and pstack on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: debugging, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gdb, pstack

I tried installing gdb and pstack on EC2 Instance with Amazon Linux AMI (it was not installed by default), and it's not working.

Tried:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-21-ab-xyz ~]$ sudo yum install gdb
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package gdb available.
Error: Nothing to do

[ec2-user@ip-172-21-ab-xyz ~]$ sudo yum install pstack
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package pstack available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Tried to manually put gdb tar on AMI and compile it, but it didn't work.
Not sure where to get RPMs for AMI. Where to download the packages from ?

Can anyone guide me on how to install GDB and pstack on AMI ?

Comment: I think you can install gdb from [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/), and it is very easy: ./configure, make, make install.

Comment: @Nan Xiao - I tried it, but it didnt work. Used gdb-7.8.tar.gz and make fails.

configure: error: no termcap library found

make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/gdb/gdb-7.8'

make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Any recommendations for pstack?

Comment: "`no termcap library found`", please install [it](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/termcap/). For the `pstack`, it is only a shell script. Do you understand Chinese? If yes, please refer this [post](http://csrd.aliapp.com/?p=718), else tell me a mail address, I will send the script to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try installing termcap and let you know if it works. I don't understand chinese. You can email it to: kishykumar@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to kindly execute the below command:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

This will install all the tools required for development and build on Amazon AMI.

More on Amazon Development tools can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/products/developer-tools/).